# The equivalent function of Matlab imfilter in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I know the equivalent functions of  `conv2` and `corr2` of MATLAB are `scipy.signal.correlate` and `scipy.signal.convolve`. But the function `imfilter` has the property of dealing with the outside the bounds of the array. Like as `symmetric`, `replicate` and `circular`. Can Python do that things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the functions  `scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate` and `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to elaborate? I'm trying to replicate `profil2 = imfilter(profil,h,'replicate');` exactly.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add some solid code, I wanted `imfilter(A, B)` equivalent in python for simple 2-D image and filter (kernel). I found that following gives same result as MATLAB:

```
import scipy.ndimage
import numpy as np
scipy.ndimage.correlate(A, B, mode='constant').transpose()
```

For given question, this will work:

```
scipy.ndimage.correlate(A, B, mode='nearest').transpose()
```

Note that for some reason MATLAB returns transpose of the expected answer.

See documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate.html) for more options.

**Edit 1:**

There are more options given by MATLAB as documented [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html#inputarg_options). Specifically, if we wish to use the `'conv'` option, we have MATLAB code (for example):

```
imfilter(x, f, 'replicate', 'conv')
```

This has python equivalence with:

```
scipy.ndimage.convolve(x, f, mode='nearest')
```

Note the `'replicate'` in MATLAB is same as `'nearest'` in SciPy in python.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to replicate the exact same results for a Gaussian filter from Matlab in Python and came up with the following:

Matlab:

```matlab
A = imfilter(A, fspecial('gaussian',12,3));
```

Python:

```py
A = scipy.ndimage.correlate(A, matlab_style_gauss2D((12,12),3), mode='constant', origin=-1)
```

where `matlab_style_gauss2D` can be taken from [How to obtain a gaussian filter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190649/how-to-obtain-a-gaussian-filter-in-python)

Comment: For me I hat to set `origin` to zero to get the same results as Matlab's `imfilter` produces

Answer (score 0):

The previous options didn't work the same way as MATLAB's `imfilter` for me, instead I used `cv2.filter2D`. The code would be:

```
import cv2

filtered_image = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)
```

The original image was:
[image]

With MATLAB's `imfilter`:
[image]

With `scipy.ndimage.convolve` or `scipy.ndimage.correlate`:
[image]

And with `cv2.filter2D`:
[image]

Because of the way I saved the image from MATLAB and the one from `cv2`, they don't look exactly the same here, but trust me, they are.