# how do I implement Gaussian blurring layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, gaussianblur

I have an autoencoder and I need to add a Gaussian noise layer after my output. I need a custom layer to do this, but I really do not know how to produce it, I need to produce it using tensors.
[image]

what should I do if I want to implement the above equation in the call part of the following code?

```
class SaltAndPepper(Layer):

    def __init__(self, ratio, **kwargs):
        super(SaltAndPepper, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.ratio = ratio

    # the definition of the call method of custom layer
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        def noised():
            shp = K.shape(inputs)[1:]

         **what should I put here????**            
                return out

        return K.in_train_phase(noised(), inputs, training=training)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'ratio': self.ratio}
        base_config = super(SaltAndPepper, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

I also try to implement using lambda layer but it dose not work.

Comment: you can simply consider GaussianNoise or GaussianDropout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504785/10375049

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for **additive** or **multiplicative** Gaussian noise, then they have been already implemented as a layer in Keras: [`GuassianNoise`](https://keras.io/layers/noise/#gaussiannoise) (additive) and [`GuassianDropout`](https://keras.io/layers/noise/#gaussiandropout) (multiplicative).

However, if you are specifically looking for the blurring effect as in [Gaussian blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) filters in image processing, then you can simply use a depth-wise convolution layer (to apply the filter on each input channel independently) with **fixed** weights to get the desired output (Note that you need to generate the weights of Gaussian kernel to set them as the weights of DepthwiseConv2D layer. For that you can use the function introduced in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201686/2099607)):

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D

kernel_size = 3  # set the filter size of Gaussian filter
kernel_weights = ... # compute the weights of the filter with the given size (and additional params)

# assuming that the shape of `kernel_weighs` is `(kernel_size, kernel_size)`
# we need to modify it to make it compatible with the number of input channels
in_channels = 3  # the number of input channels
kernel_weights = np.expand_dims(kernel_weights, axis=-1)
kernel_weights = np.repeat(kernel_weights, in_channels, axis=-1) # apply the same filter on all the input channels
kernel_weights = np.expand_dims(kernel_weights, axis=-1)  # for shape compatibility reasons

# define your model...

# somewhere in your model you want to apply the Gaussian blur,
# so define a DepthwiseConv2D layer and set its weights to kernel weights
g_layer = DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size, use_bias=False, padding='same')
g_layer_out = g_layer(the_input_tensor_for_this_layer)  # apply it on the input Tensor of this layer

# the rest of the model definition...

# do this BEFORE calling `compile` method of the model
g_layer.set_weights([kernel_weights])
g_layer.trainable = False  # the weights should not change during training

# compile the model and start training...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete explanation that makes the problem simple for me. That's exactly what I was looking for. you are really expert:) does it work just in training phase or testing too?

Comment: @david You are welcome. The weights for that layer are fixed and would be applied both in training and test phases.

Comment: Hi today, could you please help me with this issue too?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713523/is-it-possible-to-send-the-output-of-batch-normalization-to-the-next-layer-inste

Comment: Hi, do you have a suggestion for this issue? no one knows about this:( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871023/how-do-i-assign-a-value-to-a-tensor-in-order-to-prevent-this-error-typeerror

Answer (score 1):

After a while trying to figure out how to do this with the code @today has provided, I have decided to share my final code with anyone possibly needing it in future. I have created a very simple model that is only applying the blurring on the input data:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model


def gauss2D(shape=(3,3),sigma=0.5):

    m,n = [(ss-1.)/2. for ss in shape]
    y,x = np.ogrid[-m:m+1,-n:n+1]
    h = np.exp( -(x*x + y*y) / (2.*sigma*sigma) )
    h[ h < np.finfo(h.dtype).eps*h.max() ] = 0
    sumh = h.sum()
    if sumh != 0:
        h /= sumh
    return h

def gaussFilter():
    kernel_size = 3
    kernel_weights = gauss2D(shape=(kernel_size,kernel_size))
    
    
    in_channels = 1  # the number of input channels
    kernel_weights = np.expand_dims(kernel_weights, axis=-1)
    kernel_weights = np.repeat(kernel_weights, in_channels, axis=-1) # apply the same filter on all the input channels
    kernel_weights = np.expand_dims(kernel_weights, axis=-1)  # for shape compatibility reasons
    
    
    inp = Input(shape=(3,3,1))
    g_layer = DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size, use_bias=False, padding='same')(inp)
    model_network = Model(input=inp, output=g_layer)
    model_network.layers[1].set_weights([kernel_weights])
    model_network.trainable= False #can be applied to a given layer only as well
        
    return model_network

a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]])
filt = gaussFilter()
print(a.reshape((1,3,3,1)))
print(filt.predict(a.reshape(1,3,3,1)))
```

For testing purposes the data are only of shape `1,3,3,1`, the function `gaussFilter()` creates a very simple model with only input and one convolution layer that provides Gaussian blurring with weights defined in the function `gauss2D()`. You can add parameters to the function to make it more dynamic, e.g. shape, kernel size, channels. The weights according to my findings can be applied only after the layer was added to the model.

Answer (score 0):

As the Error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'`, just change `K.sqrt` to `math.sqrt`, then it will work.

Comment: no, I change the code but it produces an error I put it above. I am not sure if I want to implement Gaussian blurring how do I do this??