# how do I assign a value to a tensor in order to prevent this error: TypeError: 'RefVariable' object does not support item assignment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I have a function that has one two inputs and both of them are tensor. I need to do some processes on these inputs and then used the output in my network. one of these inputs is the output of the convolution layer and I do not know how do I solve this error! I put the function below:
the below code implements this equation, `G`, `C(u)` and `C(v)` are numbers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R515.png)

```
def DCT(a, b):
    for u in range(8):
        for v in range(8):
            for x in range(8):
                for y  in range(8):
                    b[u,v] = b[u, v] + 0.25 * C(u) * C(v) * a[x, y]* np.cos((2 * x+1) * (u) * np.pi / 16) * np.cos((2 * y+1) * (v) * np.pi / 16)
```

in the above code, `a` and `b` are tensors that are produced in the following code:

```
def slicAndJpeg(img):
    for i in range (int(img.shape[1].value/8)):
        for j in range(int(img.shape[2].value/8)):
            temp=(img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8])
            tempb=K.zeros((8,8))
            DCT(temp,tempb)
            mask=quntize_mask(8,9)
            qunz=Kr.layers.multiply(mask,tempb)
            tempc=K.zeros((8,8))
            IDCT(qunz,tempc)
            img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8]=tempc
```

the produced error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 122, in 
>       decoded_noise=JPEGLayer()(decoded)#16
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File "", line 94, in call
>       return noise()
>
> File "", line 88, in noise
>       slicAndJpeg(noised_image_pad)
>
> File "", line 66, in slicAndJpeg
>       DCT(temp,tempb)
>
> File "", line 40, in DCT
>       b[u,v] = b[u, v] + 0.25 * C(u) * C(v) * a[x, y]* np.cos((2 * x+1) * (u) * np.pi / 16) * np.cos((2 * y+1) * (v) * np.pi / 16)
>
> TypeError: 'RefVariable' object does not support item assignment

but I need to do these assignments and I can not change them. do you have any suggestion? I also tried to use `K.eval` for these two inputs, but It produces another error that I think it is due to using `K.eval` before `model.fit`

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,1]

could you please tell me how can I so these assignments without error? I am a beginner in keras and I do not know many things yet, so maybe my questions are easy for you but unfortunately, confused me.  Thank you.

Comment: You can't do item assignment on a Tensor. Try to rewrite it as vector operations (if it's possible).

Comment: what does it mean with vector operation? could you please tell more about this? Does it mean we never do sth like an assignment in Tensor? so, when we have an assignment in keras what should we do? Thanks

Comment: I will appreciate your guide.

Comment: You can do item assignment. For example, you can't take a portion or and element of a Tensor and assign something to it. By vector operation I am referring to vector arithmetic ops supported by Tensorflow. For example, suppose you want to multiply two vectors `a` and `b` element-wise. You can write a foor loop and do it element-wise `c[i] = a[i]*b[i]` which is not supported by TensorFlow, or you can simply write `c = a * b` since Tensors of the same shape will be multiplied element-wise in TensorFlow.

Comment: it means I should change all above for loops to vector type, right? but is it possible? because in DCT function I have for loops which consider all elements of tensor a for each index of tensor b and it is a matrix multiply not element-wise. right? is it possible to vectorize the DCT function?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am not familiar with DCT function and cannot comment on that.

Comment: Thank you. DCT functions try to implement discrete cosine transform and I try to implement the above equation. I add an image above shows the equation .if you have any suggestion, please help me and tell your advice. Thanks.

Comment: I changed the code and in DCT function I just produce dct coefficients that do not need tensor value, but for simulating DCT I used conv2d for doing sth like DCT. but I have problem with shape changes. I post a new question for this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913348/how-do-i-change-the-shape-of-a-tensor-with-shape-64x4x4x3-to-another-shape-as-th based on your previous suggestion. do you have any advice for it? Thanks