# how do I change the shape of a tensor with shape 64x4x4x3 to another shape as the same as input to the network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to implement jpeg compression as a noise layer in keras. during my implemention, I need to change the shape and I am puzzled how can I do this. so I try to explain what did I do and what do I want to do. first, in the following function, I produced all DCT coefficient of an 8x8 block that produces a filter with shape 64x8x8. each one of these 64 filters is the DCT coefficients for one pixel in final DCT transform output.

```
def gen_filters(size_x: int, size_y: int, dct_or_idct_fun: callable) -> np.ndarray:
    tile_size_x = 8
    filters = np.zeros((size_x * size_y, size_x, size_y))
    for k_y in range(size_y):
        for k_x in range(size_x):
            for n_y in range(size_y):
                for n_x in range(size_x):
                    filters[k_y * tile_size_x + k_x, n_y, n_x] = dct_or_idct_fun(n_y, k_y, size_y) * dct_or_idct_fun(n_x,
                                                                                                            k_x,
                                                                                                            size_x)
    return filters
```

because we can not use assignment in keras, I have to implement the DCT transform using convolve layer using the following code.

```
    image_conv = Kr.backend.conv2d(image_yuv_ch,filters,strides=(8,8),data_format='channels_first')
```

but I have some problem with the above code. if the input `image_yuv_ch` was `32x32x1` and the `filters` was `64x8x8`, how would I change the shape in order to implement the convolve layer? because with these shape it produced an error. does keras consider the first number in `filters` 's shape as the number of filter and 8x8 as the size of the filter in the above code?

I also have another question. if the convolve layer produced the things I want, means output with shape 64x4x4, as we know each element of the 4x4 filter as a vector of length 64 is the DCT value of the 8x8 block of the input image and now I will need to reshape each 64 vector to 8x8 block and put them beside each other and make 32x32x1 from 64x4x4. but I really do not know how can I do this? do you have any suggestion for me? I look forward to hearing about your suggestion. Thank you.