# Equivalent of Matlab smoothdata function in python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy

I am converting a datafile from matlab to python and am running into issues involving smoothing a dataset. Say I have an array of data A defined as follows:

```
A = np.array([[0,0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,1,1,0],
[1,1,1,0,0,0]])
```

In matlab there is a built in function to smooth this to a Gaussian curve. In the code I am translating, it is defined as follows:

```
n_data = 200.0
smthdat = smoothdata(A, 2, 'gaussian', n_data)*n_data;
```

However I am running into issues with getting this function to work in python. Importantly, I am working with a set of data rather than a single value, so functions like scipy.signal.gaussian() will not work here. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190649/how-to-obtain-a-gaussian-filter-in-python/27928469#27928469